# Taking the 1st n terms of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists

I have an array which looks something like this (will have more than 5 terms but i have only used 5 terms as an example):

```
states = numpy.array([  [0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 2, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 1, 1]]
```

I cant seem to find a way to take only the 1st n terms of this array.

For example if n = 3 then:

```
states = numpy.array([  [0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 2, 0],]
```

I have tried using a loop and list.append but i keep getting the error

> "list indices must be integers, not tuple"

since it returns an array which looks like this:

`[[array([0, 0, 0])], [array([0, 0, 1])], [array([0, 2, 0])]`

There must be a simple way to do this but i have looked for hours and cant find one!

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Use slicing - `states[:n]`

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close, but it isn't working because you are mixing Python's builtin lists with NumPy's arrays. It is important to make this distinction, because they are actually quite different.

Your solution could probably be fixed by using [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) instead of `list.append`, which would return a NumPy array rather than a list.

However, a simpler and preferred method is to use [NumPy's slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing):

```
states[:n]
```